# Is barium peroxide (BaO2) paramagnetic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Is barium peroxide paramagnetic?

I couldn't find find a credible source that states if it's paramagnetic or diamagnetic.

I thought it must be cause it does have $\ce{O2^{-2}}$  in it but I'm unsure.

Whichever book I looked into just states its preparation method

Comment: It's a peroxide, not superoxide, so of course it's diamagnetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both the $\ce{Ba^{2+}}$ and $\ce{O2^{2-}}$ ions all the electrons are paired. Can you tell from this what the magnetic response is likely to be?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barium_peroxide) gives a negative magnetic susceptibility, which goes along with what would be expected from the electron pairing.

Comment: I'm so sorry , I got it messed up.